# WPF Visual States

Tags: wpf, visualstatemanager

Below is a snippet of XAML.  CAn anyone explain why even though `VisualState Name=”Determinate”` DOES NOT include any storyboard, the element (in this example) changes to its normal visual appearance ?

If I remove that line ('VisualState Name=”Determinate”/') the ProgressBar does bot revert to its original appearance. Is it because if it's not in indetreminate state it must be in determinate state, which is supported by DEFAULT functionality ?

What I am really saying is that the presence of 'VisualState Name="Determinate"/ -- even though it is supposedly said to do nothing by the comment  --  does have impact.  This impact could be seen if we comment out that visual state line and hover over the right hand pie chart.  In that scenario, the pie chart will not revert to its "normal" looking appearance.  Why is that ? What happens behaind the scene ?

```
<Application x:Class="WindowsApplication1.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WindowsApplication1"
StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="foregroundBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="LightGreen"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="DarkGreen"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="progressPie" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
            <!-- Resources -->
            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <local:ValueMinMaxToPointConverter x:Key="converter1"/>
                <local:ValueMinMaxToIsLargeArcConverter x:Key="converter2"/>
            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <!-- Visual Tree -->
            <Viewbox>
                <!-- Visual State Groups -->
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState Name="Determinate"/>
                        <!-- Nothing to do for this state -->
                        <VisualState Name="Indeterminate">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="pie" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="backgroundNormal" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="backgroundIndeterminate" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Grid Width="20" Height="20">
                    <Ellipse x:Name="backgroundIndeterminate" Opacity="0" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Width="20" Height="20">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Yellow"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Brown"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="backgroundNormal" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                    <Path x:Name="pie" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry>
                                <PathFigure StartPoint="10,10" IsClosed="True">
                                    <LineSegment Point="10,0"/>
                                    <ArcSegment Size="10,10" SweepDirection="Clockwise">
                                        <ArcSegment.Point>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter1}">
                                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Value"/>
                                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Minimum"/>
                                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Maximum"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </ArcSegment.Point>
                                        <ArcSegment.IsLargeArc>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter2}">
                                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Value"/>
                                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Minimum"/>
                                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Maximum"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </ArcSegment.IsLargeArc>
                                    </ArcSegment>
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathGeometry>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                </Grid>
            </Viewbox>
            <!-- Only one Trigger -->
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="pie" Property="Fill">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Gray"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="White"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>


<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="WindowsApplication1.Window1">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ProgressBar Foreground="{StaticResource foregroundBrush}" Width="100"
      Height="100" Value="0" Template="{StaticResource progressPie}" Margin="10"/>
    <ProgressBar Foreground="{StaticResource foregroundBrush}" Width="100"
      Height="100" Value="10" Template="{StaticResource progressPie}" Margin="10"/>
    <ProgressBar Foreground="{StaticResource foregroundBrush}" Width="100"
      Height="100" Value="50" Template="{StaticResource progressPie}" Margin="10"/>
    <ProgressBar Foreground="{StaticResource foregroundBrush}" Width="100"
      Height="100" Value="75" Template="{StaticResource progressPie}" Margin="10"/>
    <ProgressBar Foreground="{StaticResource foregroundBrush}" Width="100"
      Height="100" Value="100" Template="{StaticResource progressPie}" Margin="10"/>
    <ProgressBar Foreground="{StaticResource foregroundBrush}" Width="100"
      Height="100" Value="10" IsEnabled="False" Template="{StaticResource progressPie}" Margin="10"/>
    <ProgressBar Foreground="{StaticResource foregroundBrush}" Width="100" 
      Height="100" Value="10" IsIndeterminate="True" Template="{StaticResource progressPie}" Margin="10" MouseEnter="RoutedEventHandler"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public class ValueMinMaxToIsLargeArcConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,
            CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double value = (double)values[0];
            double minimum = (double)values[1];
            double maximum = (double)values[2];

            // Only return true if the value is 50% of the range or greater
            return ((value * 2) >= (maximum - minimum));
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter,
            CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }



       public class ValueMinMaxToPointConverter : IMultiValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,
               CultureInfo culture)
            {
                double value = (double)values[0];
                double minimum = (double)values[1];
                double maximum = (double)values[2];

                // Convert the value to one between 0 and 360
                double current = (value / (maximum - minimum)) * 360;

                // Adjust the finished state so the ArcSegment gets drawn as a whole circle
                if (current == 360)
                    current = 359.999;

                // Shift by 90 degrees so 0 starts at the top of the circle
                current = current - 90;

                // Convert the angle to radians
                current = current * 0.017453292519943295;

                // Calculate the circle's point
                double x = 10 + 10 * Math.Cos(current);
                double y = 10 + 10 * Math.Sin(current);

                return new Point(x, y);
            }

            public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter,
                CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
        }
    }

    namespace WindowsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Window1 : Window
        {
            public Window1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            public void RoutedEventHandler(object sender,    RoutedEventArgs e)

            {
                int a = 0;
                ((ProgressBar)sender).IsIndeterminate = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because if it's not in indeterminate state it must be in determinate state, which is supported by DEFAULT functionality ?

Yes, that is correct.  If you look at the control template's content, you should see that it is configured in the determinate state -- so that is its default.  Changing to the "Indeterminate" state applies its storyboard, and then changing back to "Determinate" reverses the effects of that storyboard.

> This impact could be seen if we comment out that visual state line and hover over the right hand pie chart. In that scenario, the pie chart will not revert to its "normal" looking appearance. Why is that? What happens behind the scene ?

I'm not certain, but my guess is that when the control attempts to go to the "Determinate" state, the runtime sees that no such state exists, and throws an exception (you could check the Output window in Visual Studio to confirm this).  In any case, this behavior is not surprising -- if you want a control to function correctly, you need to include in its control template all of its [named parts and visual states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334413%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: Would you know how 'changing back to "Determinate" reverses the effects'  ? I would assume -- but am not sure -- that the visual state manager will be mart enough to associate the determinate state with some properties set to some value (dictated by the Controls Template definition) such that once the state is switched from indeterminable to determinate, it will apply those properties.  Or perhaps it builds a default storyboard per the determinate state (this storyboard being consistent with the Control Template's content ) ?

Comment: ... In that sense, if a storyboard were included with respect to Determinate state, then Visual State manager would have executed that storyboard rather than the implicit storyboard, could that be the case ?  ...my only goal is to understand how states really work .

Comment: @WITL your second comment is correct: if you include a storyboard with the Determinate state, then the Visual State manager would execute that.  I don't know the internals of how the "implicit storyboard" works, only the effect: if you go to a state with no Storyboard (ie, Determinate), then the effects of the active VisualState  in the same VisualStateGroup (ie, Indeterminate) will be rolled back.